# Selecting a column name defined by a calculated day of the week in a function

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have the following code which works great in a stored procedure.

```
SET @SQL = 'SELECT @Hours = ' + datename(dw,@DateFor) + ' FROM tblHours WHERE EmployeeID = ' + CAST(@EmployeeID AS VarChar(10))

SET @Parm = '@Hours int output'
EXEC sp_executesql @SQL, @Parm, @Hours OUT
```

But I need to do this in a function, so I can't use EXEC.

Can any one help change my select to not need an EXEC?

```
tblHours
╔════════════╦════════╦═════════╦═══════════╦══════════╦════════╗
║ EmployeeID ║ Monday ║ Tuesday ║ Wednesday ║ Thursday ║ Friday ║
╠════════════╬════════╬═════════╬═══════════╬══════════╬════════╣
║ 1          ║ 8      ║ 8.5     ║ 8.5       ║ 8.5      ║ 8.5    ║
║ 2          ║ 8      ║ 9       ║ 9         ║ 9        ║ 9      ║
║ 3          ║ 8      ║ 0       ║ 0         ║ 8        ║ 8      ║
╚════════════╩════════╩═════════╩═══════════╩══════════╩════════╝
```

Thanks,
Ricky

Comment: Can you explain why you need it to be a function and not a stored procedure? A CLR function might be your best option in this case.

Comment: You can't run an Exec command inside a SQL function

Comment: You'd better describe why do you need dynamic query in this case at all.

Comment: It's called by another function thats used in a select. I'm not normally keen on functions but I've inherited the code and I'm trying to work with it.

Comment: Is that a full code?

Comment: There is a lot more code in the function, but this is the problem. I need to get rid of the exec if possible or look at changing everything to stored procedures.

Comment: Sorry, I did not get that `datename` defines column name. This can approve usage of dynamic sql. But again, why do you need to get it via dynamic query if all columns are already named after weekdays and you need to return table with all possible weekdays? `select *` does the same thing, doesn't it?

Comment: Select * will return all columns, but I actually want a specific column. Though I can now see how I could return all the columns as a string and then extract my specific value. I just thought there might be a much better way of doing this.

Comment: Table demonstrated in your question - is this a desired output or the source table?

Comment: Source table. All I want is the value from one of the day columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

without dynamic sql:

```
set @Hours =
  (
    SELECT 
      case datename(dw,@DateFor)
        when 'Monday' then h.Monday
        ...
        when 'Sunday' then h.Sunday
      end
    FROM tblHours h
    WHERE h.EmployeeID = @EmployeeID
  )
```

`set` will work as automatic validation that only one row was returned by the query.

Comment: Never thought of using a CASE to define the column to select. Thank you!